# Caused: java.io.IOException: Unable to read /var/jenkins_home/config.xml

Tags: linux, docker, jenkins

When I run jenkins I got this error:

```
Caused: java.io.IOException: Unable to read /var/jenkins_home/config.xml
```

docker compose conf :

```
Volumes:
  - jenkins_home:/var/jenkins_home
```

what should I do to make it  work please  ?

Answer (score 1):

In Docker Compose, you need to specify the local directory where you want to store the Jenkins home data. The volumes directive in your docker-compose.yml file should map a local directory to the /var/jenkins_home directory in the container.

Here's how you can correct your docker-compose.yml file:

```html
volumes:
  - ./jenkins_home:/var/jenkins_home
```

Comment: Hi thanks for coming back, but the problem is not on docker compose file but in the config.xml

Comment: I suggest validating your configuration file using an XML validator in order to identify any errors that may not be immediately visible (if the changes were made manually). If there are no permission issues, it is advisable to create a backup of the config.xml file and delete the previous configuration. Upon starting Jenkins, a new config.xml file will be generated. However, it should be noted that if you are not utilizing JCasC, you will be required to manually configure Jenkins.